# Wiring Controllers In Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

#### TLDR

How can I wire controllers in `resources.groovy`?

#### Story

I have two controllers `ProviderAController` and `ProviderBController`
who both implement `ProviderControllerContract` interface.

```
interface ProviderControllerContract {
  abstract def actionX()
  abstract def actionY()
}

  
class ProviderAController implements ProviderControllerContract {
  @Override
  def actionX() { ... }

  @Override
  def actionY() { ... }
}


class ProviderBController implements ProviderControllerContract {
  @Override
  def actionX() { ... }
 
  @Override
  def actionY() { ... }
}
```

Depending on external decisions, my Grails application is supposed to
use only one of the controllers at a time (e.g. redirect to their
actions in other controllers or views).

```
SomeController {
 
  def someAction() {
    // ...
    redirect(controller: 'providerController', action: 'actionX')
  }

}
```

OR

```
<g:form action="${g.createLink(controller: 'providerController',
    action: 'actionX')">
  ...
</g:form>
```

To make this work, I supposed I should add a reference to this
`providerController` bean in `resources.groovy` and wire it to a
specific implementation, e.g. `ProviderAController`:

```
// resources.groovy
beans = {

  providerController(ProviderAController)

}

// UrlMappings.groovy
...
'/foo/bar/x'(controller: 'providerController', action: 'actionX')
...
```

However, as you may have guessed, this setup is not working as expected.
I suspect I'm missing something trivial or have misunderstood the whole
concept in the first place. I'd appreciate any help/hint.

*Originally posted on [Grails dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-dev-discuss/vmgWcpqv1Eo), however now that I think again, it seems I should have posted this on Grails user list :-)*

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I have seen this [post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/grails-goodness-using-spring-bean.html) that could work also for controllers.

In the resources.groovy try this:

```
beans = {
    springConfig.addAlias 'providerController', 'providerAController'
}
```